# mysql select child from parent and use it in another query

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables.

TABLE_1

```
category_id   name   parent_id
1             test    0
2             test1   1 
3             test2   1  
4             test3   1
5             test4   2
.
```

TABLE_2

```
pro_id   category_id   name
1        2            prod1
2        2            prod2
3        3            prod3
4        5            prod4
.
. 
.
```

I need to do this

1. get all `category_id`s where `parent_id = given...` (say '1')
2. query in another table with `where in (all the ids returned from 1) )`...  **should be `where in ('2,3,4')` in the example case**

OUTPUT

all fields of `pro_id` (1,2,3 in this case) from TABLE 2..

tried this.. (hoping this will work :) )

```
select * from TABLE_2 
where category_id in (select category_id from TABLE_1 where parent_id = 1)
```

but no result.

I could have done all this in PHP script. But had a problem with pagination. So I want to make it work in one query.

So is it possible to do this? Get the result from a query and use it in other in a single query? If so then I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is weird .. but the query i provided was working.... :) :)

```
select * from TABLE_2 where category_id in (select category_id from TABLE_1 where parent_id = 1)
```

anywasy thanks guys...

Comment: Try with join rather than sub-query, this is better approach. check my answer

Comment: ok sure thanks...  (not tired yet) but i think this gives NULL values for other categories rite???

Comment: if you want to avoid null categories try with inner join

Answer (score 3):

IN is a very slow operator, since SQL normally evaluates it as a series of WHERE clauses separated by "OR" (WHERE x=Y OR x=Z OR...).

So try this

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM TABLE_1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t2.category_id = t1.category_id
WHERE t1.parent_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide field in the WHERE-clause.

```
select * from TABLE_2 where category_id in (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM TABLE_1 t1
JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON 
t2.category_id = t1.category_id
WHERE t1.parent_id = 1
```

But the query you have written above should work.

Comment: yes... this is weird... query i provided is wokring now...thanks anyways.... appreciate your help.... +1 for ur help...